# Fastest way to plot 2d georeferenced array into a tms like tile pyramid

Tags: python, plot, leaflet, gdal, wms

I am having a 2d numpy array serving georeferenced information like a radar image or a temperature field. I know the coordinates of all points and can define the bounding box in EPSG:3857.

What is the fastest way to plot this data into a tms tile pyramid?

A well known solution is to plot data as a geotiff and use `gdal2tiles` but this is very slow for hgh zoom levels >10.

I hope anyone can recommend a software doing this or can provide a code snippet. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198013/numpy-to-geotiff-for-use-with-gdal

Comment: Does not look Like that is a proper way to Plot hundreds of images or slice one big Image Into tiles.

Comment: It looks proper to me. Convert the numpy data to any gdal format, then slice the gdal-compatible raster into a tile pyramid. Then you can analyze any performance bottlenecks later.

Comment: But then I have to loop through all tiles to plot the data.  That sounds not fast to me. Maybe I am thinking to complicate about plotting.

Comment: Please *measure* your performance before complaining about performance. Avoid [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil#80092) whenever possible, and stick to facts.